# How to Add two Select tags with Submit button to Jump to url URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to setting up a dropdown menu selector.

When visitor choose "Volvo" from the first dropdown menu and choose "White" from the second dropdown menu then hit submit button. He should jump to URL 1, and so on.

Can I do this?

```html
<body>

  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form target="_blank" action="/page_url" method="get">
  <select name="carbrand">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel" selected="selected">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <select name="carcolor">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="red" selected="selected">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>

  <br/><br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

You could use `form` and `input` tags.

As above example, after clicking on the button a new page will open (`target="_blank"` attribute opens the URL in a new window or tab).

In this case using the `method="get"` form attribute, the values of the dropdowns are passed as parameters in URI `/page_url?carbrand=opel&carcolor=red`. If instead the `method="post"` form attribute used, the values of the dropdowns aren't present in the URL.

Comment: But submit button now send all selections to the same URL. While I need the visitor who chose Opel+White go to URL-1, and who chose Opel+Blue go to URL-2 and so on. Can this be done??

Comment: it is possible to do this in many ways, an example via javascript at this link https://jsfiddle.net/riswit/3wz5L10b/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this like this :

````
    <option value="volvo"><a href='http://example.com'>Volvo</a></option>

  </select>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can put your drop downs into a form, that way when the form is submitted (with your submit button), you can then use the form values to determine what content to load.

Alternatively, if you want to do this without the server side logic, you replace your submit button with a simple `<button type="button"...>` and have the on click of that button handle the logic to open the page you want.